# Como verificar se uma entidade encontra-se rastreada com o Entity framework Core 2.0.3?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Em meu repositório, preciso criar uma função que me retorne um "booleano" informando se uma Entidade está sendo "Rastreada". Preciso fazer isso, pois quando faço um "update" da mesma entidade mais de uma vez, dentro de uma transação, o Entity framework estoura um erro informando que a entidade está sendo rastreada.
Eu tentei verificar, mas o retorno está sendo sempre false. Alguém sabe uma maneira de como verificar isso?

```
public bool IsTracked(TEntity obj)
{
    var teste = Db.Entry(obj).State;
    return teste == EntityState.Modified;
}
```

REPOSITÓRIO COMPLETO:

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected readonly RetaguardaContext Db;
    protected readonly DbSet<TEntity> DbSet;

    public Repository(RetaguardaContext context)
    {
        Db = context;
        DbSet = Db.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual void Add(TEntity obj)
    {
        DbSet.Add(obj);
    }

    public virtual TEntity GetById(int id)
    {
        return DbSet.Find(id);

        //tentativa
        //var entity = DbSet.Find(id);
        //Db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
        //return entity;
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll(bool @readonly = false)
    {
        return @readonly ?
            DbSet.AsTracking() :
            DbSet;
    }

    public virtual void Update(TEntity obj)
    {
        DbSet.Update(obj);
    }

    public virtual void Remove(int id)
    {
        var obj = DbSet.Find(id);
        if (obj != null)
            DbSet.Remove(obj);
    }

    public int SaveChanges()
    {
        return Db.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Db.Dispose();
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public void Remove(params object[] keyValues)
    {
        var obj = DbSet.Find(keyValues);
        if (obj != null)
            DbSet.Remove(obj);
    }

    public TEntity GetByIds(params object[] keyValues)
    {
        return DbSet.Find(keyValues);
    }

    public int GetMax(Expression<Func<TEntity, int>> select)
    {
        return DbSet.Select(select).Max();
    }       

    public bool IsTracked(TEntity obj)
    {
        var teste = Db.Entry(obj).State;
        return teste == EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return DbSet.AsTracking().Where(predicate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

poderia testar dessa forma.

```
public bool IsTracked(TEntity obj)
{
   var response = Db.Entry(obj).State = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Modified;
   SaveChanges();
   return response;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica @Matheus!